# Cannot disable a simple a tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I can't find a way to disable the a tag on the li. Everything appears as disabled but I'm still able to click it.

I'm using AngularJS and Bootstrap

How should I disable to click on the tab?

vm.actions.documentsCompleted is false. The first ng-class on the li works well. But I'm still able to click on the tab.

```
<li ng-class="{'disabled': !vm.actions.documentsCompleted}" class="nav-item">
   <a ng-disabled="!vm.actions.documentsCompleted" class="nav-link " id="risk-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#risk" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false"><span ng-class="{'d-none' : !saved.savedRisk}"><i class="far fa-check fa fa-sm"></i></span> Text</a>
```

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may be able to get away with using a `button` with the `btn-link` class. It looks like a link but behaves like a button so it can be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

According to the bootstrap docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/ to disable the link in any nav element you should use the `disabled` class on the `<a>` element, something like this:

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a ng-disabled="!vm.actions.documentsCompleted" class="nav-link" ng-class="{'disabled': !vm.actions.documentsCompleted}" id="risk-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#risk" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false"><span ng-class="{'d-none' : !saved.savedRisk}"><i class="far fa-check fa fa-sm"></i></span> Text</a>
```

For bootstrap v3.* the code you provided should work as noted in the docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav-disabled-links

Comment: doesn't work....

Comment: Have you tried putting the class manually with dev tools. Also what version on Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: bootstrap version is 3.3.7

Comment: Try doing this manually to see if it works https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav-disabled-links if not check your angular code and see if the variable in your vm is actually correct